# Deployment error with docusaurus when trying to deploy via now to Vercel(Zeit)

Tags: node.js, npm, deployment, markdown, docusaurus

I am facing a big problem while deploying to vercel via now.

I am able to successfully execute `yarn run build` and `yarn run start`, but when I am trying to deploy it via `now`.

I get this error

```
Error: You have 'doc' in your headerLinks, but no 'docs' folder exists one level up from 'website' folder. Did you run `docusaurus-init` or `npm run examples`? If so, make sure you rename 'docs-examples-from-docusaurus' to 'docs'.
2020-08-24T18:48:36.566Z      at forEach (/vercel/58999d95/node_modules/docusaurus/lib/core/nav/HeaderNav.js:253:15)
2020-08-24T18:48:36.566Z      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
2020-08-24T18:48:36.566Z      at HeaderNav.renderResponsiveNav (/vercel/58999d95/node_modules/docusaurus/lib/core/nav/HeaderNav.js:248:17)
2020-08-24T18:48:36.566Z      at HeaderNav.render (/vercel/58999d95/node_modules/docusaurus/lib/core/nav/HeaderNav.js:325:19)
2020-08-24T18:48:36.566Z      at processChild (/vercel/58999d95/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3134:18)
2020-08-24T18:48:36.567Z      at resolve (/vercel/58999d95/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2960:5)
2020-08-24T18:48:36.567Z      at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/vercel/58999d95/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3435:22)
2020-08-24T18:48:36.567Z      at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/vercel/58999d95/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3373:29)
2020-08-24T18:48:36.567Z      at renderToStaticMarkup (/vercel/58999d95/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:4004:27)
2020-08-24T18:48:36.567Z      at renderToStaticMarkupWithDoctype (/vercel/58999d95/node_modules/docusaurus/lib/server/renderUtils.js:16:48)
2020-08-24T18:48:36.607Z  error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Here is my file structure.

```
example
├── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
├── docs
│   ├── doc1.md
│   ├── doc2.md
│   ├── doc3.md
│   ├── exampledoc4.md
│   └── exampledoc5.md
└── website
    ├── README.md
    ├── blog
    │   ├── 2016-03-11-blog-post.md
    │   ├── 2017-04-10-blog-post-two.md
    │   ├── 2017-09-25-testing-rss.md
    │   ├── 2017-09-26-adding-rss.md
    │   └── 2017-10-24-new-version-1.0.0.md
    ├── core
    │   └── Footer.js
    ├── package.json
    ├── pages
    │   └── en
    │       ├── help.js
    │       ├── index.js
    │       └── users.js
    ├── sidebars.json
    ├── siteConfig.js
    ├── static
    │   ├── css
    │   │   └── custom.css
    │   └── img
    │       ├── favicon.ico
    │       ├── oss_logo.png
    │       ├── undraw_code_review.svg
    │       ├── undraw_monitor.svg
    │       ├── undraw_note_list.svg
    │       ├── undraw_online.svg
    │       ├── undraw_open_source.svg
    │       ├── undraw_operating_system.svg
    │       ├── undraw_react.svg
    │       ├── undraw_tweetstorm.svg
    │       └── undraw_youtube_tutorial.svg
    └── yarn.lock
Done in 0.57s.
```

This is actually generated via `npx docusaurus-init`, but still unable to deploy.

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by doing `npm install` and `yarn run build`